# jQuery alternative to javascript:openWindow

Tags: jquery, forms, popup, lightbox

I'm redesigning our content management system's image editor. It currently uses `javascript:openWindow` to open an HTML page with a URL variable (i.e. `MediaAdd?articleid=3709`). This page contains a simple POST form.

I'm looking at jQuery Lightbox alternatives to keep everything in the same window and avoid popups. Would something like [**Ceebox**](http://catcubed.com/2008/12/23/ceebox-a-thickboxvideobox-mashup/) or [**Fancybox**](http://fancybox.net/)'s iframe option be able to handle the page's POST form?

If not, then what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lightbox alternative has a callback function so you can add events (including onload events I think) within the modal window.  It's a great one, and lightweight:

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

**Note:**

You can handle the post a couple of ways.

Option 1: Make an ajax callback api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/  You would add this event on submit.
Option 2:  Call an iframe in colorbox (actually works elegantly)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So the iframe call would go to MediaAdd?articleid=3709, right?

Comment: Whatever the URL generated by your PHP/Asp/etc. script is.  You don't want it to be a static value, so set it as a variable.

Comment: You can thank me by selecting my answer as the chosen one = )

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [JQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) but you have to manage your ajax post and callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used jqModal pretty successfully before. It's not iframe based and it should let you do pretty much everything you need.

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/